# Resultant force on a system with two frames linked by pulleys which are grounded

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I have an application where I have a system which is static and carries a payload. The system has an external and internal frames and the external frame is 'suspended' via wires and pulleys as shown below:
[image]

Frame A is suspended by two wires and carries a payload M.
Frame B has the two pulleys attached to it and is sat on a small block.
The cables attach to frame A and the ground.
Frames, block and wires are rigid (no stretching).

Considering this as a static problem, my calculations appear to be:

- frame a: -W + 2xT1 = 0
- pulley:  -2xT2 + Fb = 0
- frame b: 2x Fb - F = 0
- cables: T1=T2=Fg

Therefore: F= 2xFb
Which equates to: F = 2xW

In my head, it is not intuitive that the load gets doubled. I think I must doing something wrong with my FBDs. Any tips?

Comment: Just to specify, the pulleys are attached to frame B but are still free to rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, $F = 2W$. One way you can check this is by using conservation of energy: if $M$ is allowed to move a tiny bit downward, if you look closely, you will see that frame B moves half as much. The work done by $W$ must be equal to the work done against the upward normal force $F$ (assuming frictionless, massless pulleys etc.), so
$$ W \Delta x = F \frac{\Delta x}{2} $$
$$ F = 2 W. $$

Intuitively, the total force being applied on the ground is actually $W$, as expected. However, this total force is not only due to $F$, but also due to $2F_g$ pointing upward. We have
$$ W = F - 2F_g = F - 2T_1 = F - W $$
$$ F = 2 W. $$

Comment: thanks! Good idea to look at it from an energy perspective.